# Show product of a category in a custom page

Tags: product, category, magento-1, page-layouts, redirect-url

I create a category with some product. Also create a custom layout for my page that I add new `cms page` with this layout that I created. I need to have this page with my layout because I want to add some `php` code just for this page. I redirect category to this page but my problem is here that products that I added to this category doesn't show in page.

**Now I want to know how can I show products in this page?**

Steps that I created my custom layout:

1.) I create a `phtml` file with `2columns-left.phtml` layout and it's name is `renewpage.phtml` and it's address is: `app/design/frontend/default/celebrity/template/page`.

2.) I added it's `config.xml` in `app/code/local/Renew/Page/etc/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Renew_page>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Renew_page>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <page>
            <layouts>
                <renewpage translate="label">
                    <label>Renew_page</label>
                    <template>page/renewpage.phtml</template>
                    <layout_handle>Renew_page</layout_handle>
                </renewpage>
                <!-- add more layouts here -->
            </layouts>
        </page>
    </global>
</config>
```

3.) And add `Renew_page.xml` in `app/etc/modules/Renew_page.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Renew_page>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Page />
            </depends>
        </Renew_page>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: You want a particular category product

Comment: @Manojkothari: Can you explain me more please?

Comment: You Want a particular category in custom page

Comment: @Manojkothari: I am new in magento, can you guide me how can I do this? thanks.

Comment: you create 1 category and assign what and all product you want in custom page

Comment: @Manojkothari: I created my category with it's product and also have my custom page but how can I show products in page?

Answer (score 0):

You could show a list of product using `app/design/frontend/default/URDESIGN/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

If want to get a individual category and display with a simple config, you could do this on the `list.phtml` `line 110` on else, to display a grid mode:

```
<?php else: ?>
    <?php // Grid Mode ?>
    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <table class="products-grid" id="products-grid-table">
    <?php
        $_columnCount = 1; // $this->getColumnCount()
        $_items = $_productCollection->getItems();
        shuffle($_items);
        $max_items = 6; // Show 6 items
        $personal_count = 1;
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($_items as $_product):
    ?>
```

EDIT:

If you want to call it, just call like:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="###CAT_ID###" template="catalog/product/new-list-example.phtml"}}
```

And switch `###CAT_ID###` for the category that you want to display.

If have any problem, comment it.

Comment: Why I should add this code in `list.phtml`? I don't want to change in files and I create my custom layout for my page that I want to show products in this page, I don't understand why you said change `list.phtml`.

Comment: Its correct, i write quickly but i say you could.
Instead of this, you could create a new file called `new-list-example.phtml` and copy `list.phtml` and add this changes.

Comment: I use your code but nothing happen.

Comment: Did you insert the code that i put at the end to insert the list?

Comment: Yes I insert `block` in my page in admin panel.

Comment: Did you insert the code exactly as i say?
Did you call a category_id valid?
Did you try to display a echo to be sure that the phtml is configured correctly?

Comment: I test it again, sorry I comment the content page and because of it, nothing happen, I correct it and now I get this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in: ...../list2.phtml on line 111`.

Comment: To evade problems with inserting the code, i give you my list2 exactly:
http://pastebin.com/XXpDmGPY

Comment: Thank you so much, I added your file and it's show products but not like category page and all data in this page so messed up. I want to show products exactly like category page.

Comment: If you want to get same as the category page, just copy the list.phtml to list2.phtml , and call with the {{block ...}}  , and its done.

Comment: Page so messed up, is it possible I should add something for page?

Comment: Yeah, you could order like this
`{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="XXX" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"  sort_by="position" default_direction="desc" }}`

Comment: Unfortunately nothing change and page show messed up, I really don't know why it's happen.

Answer (score 0):

You copy `app/design/frontend/default/Customtheme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` and paste it same folder `app/design/frontend/default/Customtheme/template/catalog/product/rename.phtml`

Then call this code in your custom page

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="Your Category ID Here" template="catalog/product/rename.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Its the same as i say before but without the upgrade of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

In summary then, you need to do the following things:

- Create a new category
- Create a new module
- Create a new layout XML file in the module
- Create a new template in the module
- Create a new Block Class in the module
- Add the logic to pull out the products from your new category in there
- Call the method from your template

All these individual steps are documented elsewhere on the web, I won't repeat that information here.